# How to upgrade android app gui

Tags: android, user-interface, flash

I've written android app, and its working. Now i got task to upgrade app's GUI. I have new UI made in Flash.

Is there any way to import .swf files into existing android app? and used them like layouts or some kind of custom views?

Or how to make some kind of callback functions, that are triggered when something happens in flash GUI, and process some JAVA/Android code? Help...

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Flash as a GUI for an Android application, and there's not a tool to "convert" either.  You'll have to either make a normal Android application, or write your app as a web application.

I don't know if you can use a .swf on the device in a WebView, it *may* be possible, but boy does that seem like the wrong solution.

Comment: its seem wrong too me, too...but my boss wants fansy flash GUI in android -.-

Comment: Then you need to explain to him that it can't be flash, though it can still be fancy.

Comment: I've exceeded implementing .swf file into custom dialog with some hacks, and i can interact with it using keyboard. Now i need to implement back loop from flash app, to interact with socket in android. HARDCORE :)